# Can you use a formula in the value of an XML attribute on Android?

Tags: android, xml

I have the following in my /res/values/dimens.xml :

```
<dimen name="page_pad">5dip</dimen>
<dimen name="page_pad_double">10dip</dimen>
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve something like this instead:

```
<dimen name="page_pad">5dip</dimen>
<dimen name="page_pad_double">@dimen/page_pad * 2</dimen>
```

I do not have access to the java files, need to accomplish this in XML only. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to accomplish that. You can only specify a constant value.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. No wonder I couldn't find anything in the Android Dev Guide (though I rarely can :) )

Comment: Well it is a crazy place to search for answers, but it is improving since last year.